# Query to output results based on foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 table in MySQL:
**products** (id(int), title(varchar), description(varchar), add_date(datetime)),
**images** (id(int), product_id(int), image_file(varchar), main_image(binary), date_add(datetime)).
Column *main_image* has value 1 for just one of the product images, the rest are 0. Because of a mistake in the code, some images where added in the table with no *main_image* = 1. I need to fix this. How can I select all the products that do not have one *main_image* = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the `MAX` of all the values of `main_image` for each product, selecting only those products that have a `MAX` equal to 0 (i.e. no value which is `1`):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM images
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING MAX(main_image) = 0
```

If required you can use this as a subquery and `JOIN` it to the products table (or use it in an `IN` expression) to get the details of those products e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE id IN (SELECT product_id
             FROM images
             GROUP BY product_id
             HAVING MAX(main_image) = 0)
```